# Why does Nautilus show a file and its hard link as bigger than just the file?

Tags: nautilus, files, disk-usage, hard-link

When I create a [hard link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link) to a 2 KB file (called `fun`), Nautilus shows this hard link (called `fun-hard`) as a file with the same size. These two files are pointing to same [inode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) so their combined properties should display only 2 KB as well. But Nautilus instead says their total size is 4 KB. Why?

Comment: What software is displaying their combined size as 4 kB?

Comment: I am just Selecting file,hard link and looking into properties.

Comment: Is this in Nautilus (the file browser)?

Comment: Sorry for delay in response... i am using Nautilus.. and link, information shared by Malte helped me understanding the issue...Thanks for your information sharing.

Comment: If you understand the issue now please edit and clarify your question or even better use the answer option to write the answer to your question in detail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course, if you create a hard link to a file, then both the original file and the hard link point to the same inode. In fact, both are equivalent - for the system there is no such thing as "the original" and "the link". They are simply two access points to the same inode. Consequently, they take up no more space together than if you had only one access point (except for the tiniest bit of information in the filesystem, where two pointers to some inode are stored instead of only one).

You can easily confirm this when you use a low-level filesystem utility such as, for instance, `du`. For example, here I have a directory with a single song ([FOSS Yeaaaah!](http://benjaminkerensa.com/2011/11/25/a-song-about-ubuntu-gnome-unity-foss-yeaaaah), an awesome song about Ubuntu by Ben Kerensa) of about 2.1 MB:

```
$ ls -li 
total 2124
6424897 -rw-rw-r-- 1 malte malte 2162937 Aug  7 12:53 FOSS Yeaaaah!.mp3
$ du -ch * # display size of all files, and total size
2.1M    FOSS Yeaaaah!.mp3
2.1M    total
$ du -h . # display size of current directory
2.1M    .
```

When I create a hard link, say `Link.mp3`, to the file, `du` actually recognizes that both filenames point to the same file and only displays one of both:

```
$ ln FOSS\ Yeaaaah\!.mp3 Link.mp3
$ ls -li
total 4248
6424897 -rw-rw-r-- 2 malte malte 2162937 Aug  7 12:53 FOSS Yeaaaah!.mp3
6424897 -rw-rw-r-- 2 malte malte 2162937 Aug  7 12:53 Link.mp3
$ du -ch *
2.1M    FOSS Yeaaaah!.mp3
2.1M    total
$ du -h .
2.1M    .
```

(It's displaying only the one that comes first in alphabetical order - had I named the hardlink `A.mp3`, then `du` would have displayed that one).

The behavior you're experiencing is most probably a bug or inaccuracy in whatever software you are using to display file sizes. If it's Nautilus (the standard file browser in a typical Ubuntu installation), then I can confirm that behavior. See this bug report:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/644403

It may just be "a feature, not a bug" - as Nautilus is trying to keep things simple for the average user, it simply ignores hard links. Which may not always be the best idea. Quoting from the bug report:

> Nautilus tries to keep things simple. That's why it does not offer a way to make hardlinks. But if things are already complicated - if hardlinks are already present - just ignoring them can lead to problems of its own.

In summary, if you're working with hard links, better rely on a terminal instead of some file browsing application.

Comment: ...and remember that the granularity of `du` is 4K (at least in a default-formatted ext4 filesystem). So `du` will report 4K for a file of 2K length...

Comment: To be precise, the granularity of `du` is that of the underlying file system (unless you specify `--apparent-size`), which is 4 KiB for ext4 by default for typical use cases (at least in Ubuntu). It's 64 KiB for my FAT32-formatted mobile music player with a 80 GB disk.